# Adding a reference to a list c# struct

Tags: c#, list, xna

I'm having a problem with BoundingSpheres in XNA. I'm wanting to add a BoundingSphere to a list of BoundingSpheres. At the moment it's along the lines of:

```
Aircraft(Vector3 pos, float radius, CollisionManager colMan)
{ 
    BoundingSphere sphere = new BoundingSphere(pos, radius);
    colMan.AddSphere(sphere)
}


List<BoundingSphere> spheres = new List<BoundingSphere>();

CollisionManager()
{
    spheres = new List<BoundingSphere>();
}

AddSphere(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
    spheres.Add(boundingSphere);
}
```

Rather then a reference being added, it seems to be adding the values. I believe this is because boundingSpheres are structs? How can I get round this? I tried the ref keyword, but the values still aren't being updated in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think I'll redesign my Collision Manager a bit. There should only be a limited number of objects that have moving collision boxes so I shoudl hopefully be able to find a way that won't impact too much on performance.

Comment: Consider creating an interface, let's call it `ICollidable`, which represents a collidable object and exposes its bounding geometry as a property.  Then you can just create a list of collidable objects, which is presumably what you want, and update them accordingly.  Keep in mind that passing around large structs can sometimes be worthwhile if the alternative is heap allocation, and be sure to profile your code before jumping to any conclusions about its performance.

Comment: @ColeCampbell that actually was my original thought. I had the same problem though. I created a check collision method in the interface called CheckCollision(BoundingSphere sphere). The collision manager would then call this method and pass a sphere from a list. The passed sphere would be a copy though and not reference the original bounding sphere. I can't really see a nice way around this problem that doesn't involve high coupling.

Comment: I'm unclear on why a method called `CheckCollision` would need to modify the passed bounding sphere; were I looking at the code without other guidance, its name would not lead me to think that it had side effects.  But why not `CheckCollision(ICollidable collidable)`?

Comment: @ColeCampbell It doesn't have to modify the passed sphere, but that passed sphere would always contain the values the sphere had when it was added to the list. Surely the same problem would occur passing an ICollidable instead? The only way I could see that working is if each ICollidable object had a way of updating it's respective item in the list which sounds heavily coupled? Though perhaps that's unavoidable...

Comment: The idea is that `ICollidable` would be implemented on a class that exposes the `BoundingSphere` through a property.  Because it's a class, only the reference would be stored in the list, so accessing the `BoundingSphere` property would always give you an up-to-date value.

Comment: @ColeCampbell Ahh, yes I see. I do have a suspicion I may have tried that before and for whatever reason I couldn't get it working. but I'll try that again. I do now have a "working" collision manager but I'm not sure how happy I am with it and will probably rewrite at some point. Cheerd for the input.

Answer (score 2):

To be straightforawrd, you can't, at least not directly.  Structs are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), and are thus passed and stored by value.  Even judicious use of the `ref` keyword won't get around it because `List<T>.Item` can't return a reference to a value type.

The work-arounds are to either turn your `struct` into a `class`, or embed the `stuct` inside a `class`, or, just deal with the fact it's a value type and treat it appropriately (ie, don't try to modify local copies, but replace values in the list when the change).  The last option is, imo, the best.

Answer (score 0):

Value types are passed by value (this means that you're getting fresh new copy in the method or in the container) to avoid this you can change your struct to class, add an interface to struct declaration and box your struct to store reference to the interface instead.

But it seems that you're using mutable struct and this is a very dangerous because you can face really dangerous behavior (see [mutable structs considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mutable%20structs%20evil) for more details).

Comment: 'Mutable structs considered harmful,' like 'the stack is an implementation detail,' is one of those things that sort of goes out the window when you're dealing with high-performance scenarios like game development.  Avoiding collection pressure can be hugely important, especially on mobile/console platforms, which means that mutable structs can be a good solution to a very real problem.  The .NET Framework itself uses mutable structs for this very purpose: take a look at the implementation of the generic `List` class' enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to change the definition of [`BoundingSphere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingsphere.aspx) from a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx).  This is impossible since it's defined in [an assembly outside of your control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196942.aspx).

You can't box the structure, as every time you unbox it, you're going to get a copy of the structure you're holding.

That said, the only way you can do this (and this isn't a good idea, in my opinion) is by creating a class wrapper for the structure, and delegating all of the calls from the properties to the structure internally:

```
public class BoundingSphereWrapper
{
     // Set through constructor.
     private readonly BoundingSphere _boundingSphere = ...;

     // One of the forwarded calls.
     public ContainmentType Contains(BoundingBox box)
     {
         // Forward the call.
         return _boundingSphere.Contains(box);
     }

     // And so on...
}
```

Of course, you can't pass these class instances to members that expect a `BoundingSphere`, and you'd have to try and detect changes (which are near impossible, unless the instances are passed by reference) when you expose the underlying structure.

Namely, though, you don't really want to do this; the designers of the structure probably chose it as a structure for the following reasons:

- While mutable (which is a no-no when dealing with structures), the lifetime is intended to be limited
- There could be many of these instantiated at the same time, and it's more efficient to do this on the stack than to do it on the heap (that would cause lots of first generation garbage collections, which can definitely have an impact on performance on a gaming platform)